# Laravel 5: get URL to current action with parameters in blade

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade, view-helpers

What I want is simple: I want to place a link on my page with the URL of the same page as the actual, and want to give parameters to it.

So basically I want to reload the page with different parameters.

I tried the following, but it dont work:

```
        <a href="{{ URL::action(Route::getCurrentRoute()->getActionName(), ['foo' => $foo, 'lang' => 'de' ]) }}">DE</a>
        <a href="{{ URL::action(Route::currentRouteAction, ['bar' => $bar, 'lang' => 'en' ]) }}">EN</a>
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: What about this? `<a href="{{ URL::action(Route::getCurrentRoute() }}?param1=1&param2=2">DE</a>`

Comment: That doesnt work because my URL looks like this: http://domain.com/param1/param2/someAction

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try something like

```
<a href="{{ action("MyController@myMethod", ["params" => $bar]) }}">my link</a>
```

Comment: this will link to a specific action. but I want to link to the current action.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.6 you can use:

```html
<a href="{{ route(\Route::current()->getName(), [...])  }}">link</a>
```

If your route has a name.